# Group By is returning two rows instead of the expected one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's the query:

```
SELECT    xxx.NSN, xxx.CN
    , xxx.PN
    , xxx.[BNAME]
    , xxx.[BTYPE]
    , xxx.[BSYS]
    , yyy.[BCODE]
    , Sum(yyy.QTY) AS SumOfQTY
    , Sum(xxx.[UNIT COST]) AS [SumOfUNITCOST]
    , xxx.SS
    , yyy.[Hold]
    , yyy.[SCI]
FROM xxx INNER JOIN yyy ON xxx.CN = yyy.CN
WHERE xxx.PN='11'
GROUP BY  xxx.NSN, xxx.CN
    , xxx.PN
    , xxx.[BNAME
    , xxx.[BTYPE]
    , xxx.[BSYS]
    , yyy.[BCODE]
    , xxx.SS
    , yyy.[Hold]
    , yyy.[SCI]
    , yyy.LOC
HAVING (((yyy.[Hold]) Is Null) 
   AND ((yyy.[SCI]) Is Null) 
   AND ((yyy.LOC) != 'SHIPPED'))
ORDER BY xxx.PN;
```

And here is the data being returned:

```
NSN CN  PN  BNAME   BTYPE   BSYS    BCODE   SumOfQTY    SumOfUNITCOST   SS  Hold    SCI
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
304 CO  11  LINK    AB-12   SUB     F       9           4536.00         B17 NULL    NULL
304 CO  11  LINK    AB-12   SUB     F       5           2520.00         B17 NULL    NULL
```

Now looking at the data, I would expect to get this as a result:

```
NSN CN  PN  BNAME   BTYPE   BSYS    BCODE   SumOfQTY    SumOfUNITCOST   SS  Hold    SCI
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
304 CO  11  LINK    AB-12   SUB     F       14          7056.00         B17 NULL    NULL
```

Why is it separating the two instead of grouping them?

Comment: You don't show us the `LOC` column. Its two values might be different.

Comment: Irrelevant to the issue but the `HAVING` conditions could be moved to `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the records are in different `LOC`.  So, remove that from the `GROUP BY`.

Then you have to deal with the `HAVING` clause.  Perhaps you intend:

```
HAVING (yyy.[Hold]) Is Null) AND
       (yyy.[SCI]) Is Null) AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN yyy.LOC = 'SHIPPED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: This was it.  Thanks so much.  I'll accept it when it lets me.  Appreciate the assist, all.